# Mass Security Assignment to undefined method `attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms, attr-accessible, refinery

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Refinery with Inquiries gem. I needed to add a field to the contact form provided by the Inquiries gem; however, I get this error

```
     “WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes”
```

I had read to NOT disable the whitelist in the application.rb. So I did

```
  config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

It still didn't work. So I tried to go ahead and add the attr_accessible to

**/config/initializers/refinery/inquiries.rb**

```
  Refinery::Inquiries.configure do |config|
  attr_accessible :location
  end
```

But now I get this error

**/config/initializers/refinery/inquiries.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`attr_accessible' for main:Object (NoMethodError)**

I just need to get this form field to work. Any hints!? Please!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
attr_accessible
```

is to be used in a model's definition, not in a block. Which object is your from writing into?

Answer (score 0):

Had to run rake refinery:override model=refinery/inquiries/*

added attr_accesible option in here. Thanks!